# Where can I find tech documents for Mavic 500 RD hubs?

Tags: maintenance, hub

There is a dedicated [tech page for older Mavic Products](https://tech.mavic.com/tech-mavic/technical_manual/data_old/logon.php). However, it's access restricted. Is there any other page with manuals and tech docs for Mavic 500 hubs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User mavic-com
password dealer

It has to be noted that the 500 series hubs are probably older than the content of even this old website (which has products going back to the mid/late 90s e.g. the original CrossMax)

Comment: Oh wow, thank you. Now I only need to figure out how to open this ancient flash website :D

Comment: Is this something that should be advertised publicly in this way?

Comment: @VladimirF That’s a reasonable question, but interestingly, this has been shared quite widely in the internet. Also, this login/password scheme is so ludicrously weak that it’s almost like Mavic aren’t actually concerned about security. Also, why should they be trying to prevent people from servicing older hubs?

Comment: Given that the newer tech documents aren't hidden behind a password wall, i think it's no longer relevant. It's a legacy site that may soon be obsolete (flash is going out of production) so enjoy it while it lasts.

Comment: I was able to find a [501 service manual](https://tech.mavic.com/tech-mavic/technical_manual/data_old/tech-mavic/uk/sources/Produits/ROUTE/Composants/Moyeux/501.pdf), which is good enough for me. Sadly, manuals for the 500 or 550 are nowhere to find in the mavic tech center